# R: Compare a column of a dataframe with each elements of a list

Tags: r, list, dataframe, comparison

Who can help me, please?
I have a dataframe (df) containing various data and I have a list (lst) containing unique values from the df.
For example:

[[image: enter image description here]]

I need to compare each element in df$Col1 with the first element of lst$Col1, then with the second element, the third etc. 
Then the same procedure for the second and third columns.
If the comparison is True return 1, if not return 0.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Please read the info about [how to ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and how to give a [reproducible example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269). This will make it much easier for others to help you.

Comment: Can you post the code you have tried so far?

Comment: @Saltcress Have a look at the solution below. I was assuming that this was what you are looking for.

Answer (score 0):

you can do it with `apply` wich applies if you say `MARGIN = c(1,2)` a function to each element of a matrix / data.frame.

```
df <- data.frame(col1 = c(3,2,9,7,7,1,9), 
             col2 = c(3,6,12,7,10,4,6),
             col3 = c(7,3,10,2,2,2,10))

List <- list(col1 = c(1,2,3,7,9), 
         col2 = c(3,4,6,7,10,12), 
         col3 = c(2,3,7,10))

apply(df, MARGIN = c(1,2), function(x) x %in% List[[1]])
apply(df, MARGIN = c(1,2), function(x) x %in% List[[2]])
apply(df, MARGIN = c(1,2), function(x) x %in% List[[3]])
```

If you want to combine this you can put it in a lappy-function which applies a function to each element of a list:

```
lapply(List, function(x) apply(df, MARGIN = c(1,2), function(y) y %in% x))
```

Instead of TRUE / FALSE you wanted to have 1/0 as returning value. Just use `as.numeric()` to your logic vector

```
lapply(List, function(x) apply(df, MARGIN = c(1,2), function(y) as.numeric(y %in% x)))
```